# how to join two table to get the customize result

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables as A and B

Table A is

```
OrderID   productCode   Qty  EXT  AorderID
  1         aa1         2     1     001
  1         aa2         5     2     001
  2         bb1         3     1     002
```

Table B is

```
OrderID  BProductCode  BQty  BExt
   1        bbcc         7    1
   1        ccdd         8    2
   1        eeee         1    3
```

I want to get the result like this...

```
AorderID OrderID  productCode  Qty  Ext OrderID  BProductCode  BQty BExt 
001       1        aa1         2    1     1         bbcc         7    1
001       1        aa2         5    2     1         ccdd         8    2
NULL      NULL     NULL        NULL NULL  1         eeee         1    3
002       2        bb1         3    1     NULL      NULL         NULL NULL
```

I try to select like this ,

```
 Select A.orderID, A.productCode, A.qty , A.ext ,A.AorderID, B.OrderId , B.ProductCode , B.BQty , B.Ext A left outer join B on A.orderID = B.OrderID
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do a Full Outer Join

```
SELECT *
FROM   TableA a
       FULL OUTER JOIN TableB b
         ON a.EXT = b.BExt
            AND a.OrderID = b.OrderID
```

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ac9ca/1)

Comment: Yeah, you are correct. My bad. I didn't see the match on the **EXT** and **BExt** field.